# How can I add "<" or other sign to the item that already started in the past [Timeline]?

Tags: vis.js

I'd like to add a sign to let the users know that this item has already started in the past. How can I do that?

My idea is to check for the current window and compare to the item start date and then redraw that item. But how can I do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I got my own answer.

```js
timeline.on('changed', function (properties) {
    var visibleItems = timeline.getVisibleItems();
    $.each(visibleItems, function(index, value){
        var itemTest = $("div[data-id="+value+"]").find(".vis-item-content");
        var itemText = itemTest.text();
        if (itemTest.position().left > 0){
            if (itemText.search("<<<") == -1){
                itemTest.text("<<< " + itemText);
                }
            }else{
                itemTest.text(itemText.replace("<<< ", ""));
            }
        });
    });
};
```